# Handle event press hardware button Next and Pre?

Tags: android

I want to press hardware button Next will show Next Screen and press hardware button Pre will show Pre Screen (ViewFliper)
What do you know event press hardware button Next and Pre in Android ?
How catch event press hardware button Next and Pre in Android ?
You can watch image at here: [enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/89pjr15kpxxk1lc/android.jpg)
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the hardware button 'Next'? There is no 'Next' button for an Android phone.

Comment: I would suggest rethinking your question, because is hard to understand what you want.

Comment: hardware button Next and Pre in Android  is button right and left in next button menu

Comment: "next button menu" - where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        mViewFliper.showPrevious();
        return true;
    }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        mViewFliper.showNext();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Although I can not express enough how utterly horrible it is for an app to do something like that.